Uploading large folders to NordLocker fails
Issue
I've been evaluating NordLocker on Windows and was continuously running into issues with large folders. It was impossible to upload large folders (> 3 GB) at once – neither via desktop app nor via website. The desktop app was throwing errors without stating any reason. Not even the log files were poviding any information regarding the root cause.
On the website, the upload status simply freezes after some time - without any error message at all. In addition, the website is no option since it replaces all spaces in names by underscores.
What I've tried so far

I've scanned the logs files for some meaningful entries – to no avail.
Of course, I've tried it several times.
I've read the documentation and FAQs on the support website – to no avail.

Technical information
Windows version: Windows 10.0.22631
NordLocker desktop app: 4.25.0.0
Question
How to fix this issue? I can't imagine being the only one trying to upload more than a few MB of files.

At least, I found an – apparently inofficial – workaround:
I copy folders, which I want to upload, to NordLocker's user directory now (e.g. c:\Windows\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\NordLocker\Volumes\{LOCKERNAME}) wait for NordLocker to sync it. Luckily, that works.
